# Function containing ifelse not working in dplyr, works fine outside

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dplyr

I'd like to write a function with two inputs (x and y) to create some mutated variables in a very large dataframe. Specifically, if x=y then return x, and if x!=y then draw 1 sample from a sequence of x to y.

The function works fine when I test it outside of my datafarme, but throws an error when I try to use it within mutate. I've tried both ifelse and if_else versions.

```
library(dplyr)

smx <- function(x,y){ #Function to allow sampling if length>1
  if_else(x==y,x,sample(seq(x,y,1),1))} 
  #ifelse(x==y,x,sample(seq(x,y,1),1))} #Have also tried this with ifelse, doesn't work


smx(0,0) #This works
smx(0,5) #This works

#Create dummy data frame
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(rep(0,5)),c(seq(0,4,1))))
colnames(df) <- c("varA","varB")

df

#This doesn't work
df1 <- df %>% mutate(
  VarC = smx(varA,varB)
)
```

Ideally, my output should include a third column (VarC) in which the first row is equal to 0 (because varA=varB) and the remaining rows are a random sample between a sequence from varA to varB.

I have set up my data frame so that varA is always be smaller than varB, but I'm not certain. Appreciate any help on a clean solution to this problem!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here comes from `seq`: when using this function inside `dplyr` verb, you need to make sure the length of input is 1, which isn't the case here.

Using `rowwise()` solves the problem:

```
smx <- function(x,y){
  ifelse(x==y,x,sample(seq(x,y,1),1))
}

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(rep(0,5)),c(seq(0,4,1))))
colnames(df) <- c("varA","varB")

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(VarC = smx(varA, varB))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Rowwise: 
   varA  varB  VarC
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0
2     0     1     1
3     0     2     1
4     0     3     2
5     0     4     0
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is not working because it is not `vectorized`. First, you'll need to vectorized your function, in order to make it work inside `mutate`.

You can do that as follows:

```
vectorized_fun <- Vectorize(your_fun)
```

Your code will look like this:

```
smx_v <- Vectorize(smx)

#This works
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(VarC = smx_v(varA,varB)
)
```

Comment: Although your solution works, it seems like a waste to vectorize the whole function. Vectorizing just `seq` inside the function is cleaner. `seq2 <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))` and use `seq2` inside `mutate`.